# codeigniter rewrite rule leads to infinite loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm using CodeIgniter, and I'm getting a 500 server error when I try to visit my page.
(https://test_page.com) which redirects to 
(https://test_page.com/auth/login).
Notice how
(https://test_page.com/index.php/auth/login) still works.

1. Im using HTTPS://, and I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not.
2. I have also configured my sites-available file for the domain to allowoverride.

> Codeigniter base directory:
>   **/var/www/test_page.com/public_html**

My apache error log says:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

### httpd.conf file

```
ServerName localhost

<Directory /var/www/test_page.com/public_html>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /registration.naturebridge.org/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

### config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://test_page.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

### The solution

Edit your .htaccess to include the following (also remember to not edit it in Word or a rich text format editor as it could add extra characters and give you a compilation error).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: and what does your routes file look like? something possibly conflicting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cargo-cult programming rewrite rules. CodeIgniter gives a list of rewrites - why did you have to modify them. Anyway, let's be inspectin'.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Your Request URI will start with a /, so this won't match anything.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Same.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

You'll need to rewrite those to the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This will correctly map anything that is not a directory and not a file. However, **mod_rewrite** takes public paths and not file paths (and even if it did, yours wouldn't work - /public_html/ is usually not a valid linux path).

Change the last one to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

And things should work a bit better. The infinite loop is because it mapped /blah to /public_html/index.php?/blah, which did not exist, so it tried mapping /public_html/index.php?blah to /public_html/index.php?/public_html/index.php?blah , which does not exist...you get the idea.